# recursion to find nulls

Tags: scheme, racket

im trying to find the max value in a tree, but I'm having trouble understanding the recursion part of it.

what I have so far

```
(define mytree '(10 (5(4(2 ()()) (22()())) (21(15()()) (23 ()()))) (11(6()())(13()()))))

(define (leaf mytree)
   (and(null?(cadr mytree)) (null? (caddr mytree))))


(define (maxval mytree)
  (if (null? mytree)
   mytree
  (max (leaf(maxval (cadr mytree))) (leaf(maxval (caddr mytree))))))

(maxval mytree)
```

I'm trying to make the leaf function go through every number in the tree until it gets to the bottom numbers, where it will find the greatest value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Formatting

- Indent code, align subtrees, add space
- Name predicate with `?` at the end
- Use `tree` instead of `mytree`
- Define abstractions (`left-child`, `right-child` instead of cadr-soups)

This is more readable:

```
(define mytree
  '(10 (5 (4 (2  () ())
             (22 () ()))
          (21 (15 ()())
              (23 ()())))
       (11 (6 () ())
           (13 () ()))))

(define (tree-value tree)
  (car tree))

(define (left-child tree)
  (cadr tree))

(define (right-child tree)
  (caddr tree))

(define (leaf? tree)
  (and (null? (left-child tree)
       (null? (right-child tree))))

(define (maxval tree)
  (if (null? tree)
      '()
      (max (leaf? (maxval (left-child tree)))
           (leaf? (maxval (right-child tree))))))
```

### Recursive algorithm

The maximum value of a tree `(maxvalue tree)` is the maximum value among:

1. the value associated with the tree: `(tree-value tree)`
2. the maximum value of its left subtree: `(maxvalue (left-child tree))`
3. the maximum value of its right subtree: `(maxvalue (right-child tree))`

The degenerate case (base case) where a tree has no child is to return the value associated with the tree.
Your current algorithm does not do that. In particular:

- Why is the result of `leaf?` given to `max`?
- Why don't you check the value rooted at current tree?

You should be able to translate the above in terms of code. This should look roughly like this (untested):

```
(define (maxval tree)
  (if (leaf? tree)
      (tree-value tree)
      (max (tree-value tree)
           (maxval (left-child tree))
           (maxval (right-child tree)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Short version: you need a data definition, and test cases.

Your data definition should probably read

```
;; a binary tree is either:
;; -- <you fill in this part>, or
;; -- <you fill in this part too>
```

Then, you need test cases.

- write a test case for both cases of your data definition.

This should answer your question for you.

(In general, the stepper can be helpful, but in this case, I think the problem starts earlier.)